# What does "Activate TC Settings" do?

Tags: visual-studio, twincat

Upon installing a new TwinCAT version, an option can be selected called “Activate TC settings”. [InfoSys mentions that](https://infosys.beckhoff.com/english.php?content=../content/1033/tc3_installation/6162675979.html&id=)

> If you also want to (re-)activate the TwinCAT XAE settings, activate the associated Activate TC Settings selection boxes.

But what does this exactly mean? Which TwinCAT XAE settings are this? And what does the “re-activation” mean?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you select "Activate TC Settings" toolbars like TwinCAT PLC, TwinCAT XAE Base and the TwinCAT XAE Remote Manager will be shown. Also the TwinCAT 3 start page will be loaded on start of Visual Studio.

Comment: Finally a good description! This has always been a mystery to me! Beckhoff's documentation leaves more quesetions than answers.